# ¿Cómo devolver la lista completa cuando la entrada está vacía?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

El filtro de búsqueda funciona prácticamente como deseo, ingresas una ciudad y cuando presionas el botón te devuelve los resultados de las clínicas que coinciden con la  ciudad. El único problema es que solo puedo hacer una sola búsqueda, luego tengo que recargar la página, necesito que al borrar la ciudad de la barra de búsqueda  la lista completa vuelva a aparecer y pueda hacer otra búsqueda, usar typescript está complicando esta parte, porque no logro acceder a mi base de datos usando Clinic.

```
import React,  { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { getClinic } from '../../api/drupalAPI'
import {Clinic} from '@icofcv/common';
import contentUtils from '../../lib/contentUtils'
import Loader from '../spinner/Loader';



interface Props {
    showModalLocator: boolean,
    closeModalLocator: () => void
}


export const ClinicLocator: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, showModalLocator, closeModalLocator }) => {

     const [clinicList, setClinicList] = useState<Clinic[] | undefined >([]);
    const [text, setText] = useState("")

    const textInput = () => {
        text === "" ? clinicList : null
    }

    const fetchClinicList = async () => {
    getClinic().then((response)=>{
        console.log(response)
        setClinicList(response)
    }).catch ( (error)  => {
        console.error(error);
        throw error;
    });
}

    const handleChange = () => {
        const filterClinicList = clinicList && clinicList?.length > 0
        ? clinicList?.filter((clinic) => clinic?.province?.toLowerCase() === text.toLowerCase()) 
        : undefined;
       
       
        setClinicList(filterClinicList)
        
    }

    useEffect (() => {
    fetchClinicList();  
     }, []);



return (
        <>
              <div>
                {showModalLocator ? (
                    <>
                        <div className="justify-center items-center flex overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto fixed inset-0 z-50 outline-none focus:outline-none">
                            <div className="relative p-2 w-full max-w-3xl h-full md:h-auto">
                                {/*content*/}
                                <div className="relative bg-white rounded-lg shadow">
                                    {/*header*/}
                                    <div className="flex justify-between items-start px-4 py-3 rounded-t border-b">
                                        <h3 className="text-lg font-medium">Localizador de clinicas</h3>
                                        <button className="text-gray-400 bg-transparent hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg text-sm p-1.5 ml-auto inline-flex items-center" onClick={closeModalLocator}>
                                            <svg aria-hidden="true" className="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                                            </svg>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    {/*body*/}
                                    <div className="relative px-3 py-3 flex-auto overflow-auto modal-body">
                                        <h2 className="text-sm font-medium mb-2">¿Dónde te encuentras?</h2>
                                        <input 
                                         value={text}
                                        onChange= {(e) =>  {setText(e.target.value)
                                        textInput}}
                                        type="search" 
                                        className="w-100 bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block p-2" 
                                        placeholder="Introduce una ubicación"
                                        />
<div>
                                            <h2 className="text-sm font-medium my-3">Resultados</h2>
                                            <div className="w-100">
                                                <iframe className="w-100" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2664.3238269926374!2d-0.3805919350162851!3d39.46959682083709!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0xd604f4bee0957f3%3A0x6686ff7d230b3965!2zQy4gZGUgU2FudC
                                                BWaWNlbnQgTcOgcnRpciwgNjEsIHBpc28gMsK6LCBwdGEgMsKqLCA0NjAwMiBWYWzDqG5jaWEsIEVzcGHDsWE!5e0!3m2!1ses!2sus!4v1662388390673!5m2!1ses!2sus" loading="lazy"></iframe>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="md:mt-4 overflow-auto relative py-2">
                                                <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 gap-2">
{clinicList && clinicList?.length === 0 && (
                                                       <div>Clinica no encontrada</div>
                                                   )}
                                                   
                                                        {!clinicList ? <Loader /> :
                                                            clinicList.map((clinicFilter) => (
                                                     <div className="card bg-white px-2 py-3 h-36 md:h-32">
                                                        <button key={clinicFilter.id} type="button" className="text-left">
                                                            <div className="flex items-center gap-2 md:gap-4 md:gap-4">
                                                                <img className="h-24 w-2/5 min-w-40 object-cover object-center rounded-lg" src={contentUtils.getLargeImageUrl(clinicFilter.logo)} alt="#"/>
                                                                <div className="w-3/5">
                                                                    <div className="text-md font-medium leading-5 clinic-title uppercase">{clinicFilter.title}</div>
                                                                    <div className="flex items-center gap-2">
                                                                        <div className="text-neutral-500 text-sm">{clinicFilter.propsPhone}</div>
                                                                        <div className="text-neutral-500 text-sm">{clinicFilter.mobile}</div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div className="text-teal-600 text-sm underline clinic-mail">{clinicFilter.email}</div>
                                                                    <div className="text-neutral-500 text-sm">{clinicFilter.registry}</div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </button>
                                                        </div>
                                                            ))
                                                        }
                                                    </div>
                                                    
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                         {/*footer*/}
                                    <div className="flex items-center justify-end px-4 py-2 border-t border-solid border-slate-200 rounded-b gap-2">
                                        <button className="btn text-black text-sm background-transparent px-8 outline-none focus:outline-none focus:ring-teal-600 focus:border-teal-600" type="button" onClick={closeModalLocator}>Cancelar</button>
                                        <button className="btn bg-teal-600 hover:bg-teal-700 text-white text-sm active:bg-teal-700 px-8 outline-none focus:outline-none" type="button" onClick={handleChange} >Buscar</button>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                   
                                </div>
     </div>
                        
                        <div className="opacity-25 fixed inset-0 z-40 bg-black"></div>
                    </>
                ) : null}

            </div>

       </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Puedes usar dos hooks: uno para la lista completa y otro para la lista filtrada.

Comment: podrías mostrármelo en el código para verlo mas claro?